# When using border-collapse, how to compute border-bottom-width in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When using `table { border-collapse: collapse; }` combined with `th { border-bottom: 11px solid black }`, it seems impossible to compute the border-bottom-width in JavaScript.

`window.getComputedStyle(th).getPropertyValue('border-bottom-width')` does not help at all. Just see what [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m60wa63h/) logs to the console in different browsers...

- Chrome: `11px`
- IE11: `5.5px`
- Firefox: `6px`

If I remove `border-collapse` all browsers return `11px`, as I would expect.

Is there a more reliable way to get the precise border-width when using `border-collapse`? OR is there a way to get the height (including borders) of either the `thead`, `tr` or `th` without running into the same inconsistencies between browsers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get border width from a div with plain javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681002/get-border-width-from-a-div-with-plain-javascript)

Comment: @FabianSchultz Those answers are exactly what I'm doing here, my question is specifically about doing this when `border-collapse` is present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting! Seems like it's a [plain inconsistency between browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3435342/6941627), don't think there's a simple solution to this. Anyways, here's a hacky solution/workaround:

```js
var th = document.getElementById('th');
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(th);

table.style.borderCollapse = 'separate';
var borderHeight = style.getPropertyValue('border-bottom-width');
table.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';
console.log(borderHeight);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  border-bottom: 11px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th id="th">TH</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Tested in Chrome & Firefox, both returned `11px`.

---

EDIT: Based on @Eric N's answer, you might get lucky adding `display: block` to the `th`s. That would break the table layout then and you would need to work around that. Example for that:

```js
var th = document.getElementById('th');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(th);

var borderHeight = style.getPropertyValue('border-bottom-width');
console.log(borderHeight);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 11px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th id="th">TH</th>
    <th>TH</th>
    <th>TH</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: While these solutions work, they seems to return decimal numbers in Firefox when the zoom level is not 100%. That seems to be a separate bug, not related to tables.

Comment: Got it to work perfectly with Firefox's zoom issues, by using `th.offsetHeight - th.clientHeight` after temporarily setting `border-collapse` to `separate` as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934782/jquery-in-firefox-not-reporting-border-bottom-width-property-correctly), it appears having a display:table-cell (inherit for your cells) yield different height/border-width results in different browsers. They suggest changing the display to block on your th to force the browser to calculate that value as you would expect.